# Why is my code not waiting for the promises to complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have the following code making multiple AJAX calls (by calling ExecuteServiceMethod) in an jquery "each" loop.  I'd like to wait for all the calls to complete before calling the "__doPostBack", but it doesn't seem to be working and the postback gets called before all the ajax calls return.

Here's the calling code:

```
                $("table[id*=ChangeAllGridView]").on("hide.bs.dropdown", ".dropdown.bootstrap-select", function (event) {
                    var LotID = '<%=Session[ID + "EditedLot"]%>';
                    var SplitsList = $(event.target).children("button.dropdown-toggle").attr("title");
                    var SplitsArray = $(event.target).children("select").val();
                    var promises = [];
                    $(".selectpicker[id*=SplitDropDown]").not("[id*=SplitDropDown_All]").each(function () {
                        $(this).selectpicker("val", SplitsArray);
                        var WID = $(this).attr("id").split("_")[3];
                        var a = ExecuteServiceMethod("LotEditorWebService.asmx", "UpdateWaferSplits", ["LotID", LotID, "WID", WID, "SplitsList", SplitsList], function () { });
                        promises.push(a);
                    });
                    Promise.all(promises).then(function () {
                        __doPostBack($(event.target).attr('id'), '');
                    });
                });
```

And here's the ExecuteServerMethod routine making the AJAX call:

```
function ExecuteServiceMethod(page, fn, paramArray, successFn, errorFn) {
    var paramList = '';
    if (paramArray.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < paramArray.length; i += 2) {
            if (paramList.length > 0) paramList += ',';
            paramList += '"' + paramArray[i] + '":"' + paramArray[i + 1] + '"';
        }
    }
    paramList = '{' + paramList + '}';
    return $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: page + "/" + fn,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: paramList,
        dataType: "json",
        success: successFn,
        error: errorFn
    });
}
```

I've tried a number of iterations of this, including putting a "new Promise()" statement around the AJAX call and returning that, but nothing seems to help.
Would appreciate your help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: The return value of `ajax` implements the promise (`then`) interface since jQuery 1.5. Are you using jQuery 1.5 or higher?

Comment: another note: paramList can be simplified with `JSON.stringify`

Comment: How do you determine that the `_doPostBack()` occurs before the requests complete?

Comment: Note that using `success` is not part of the `$.ajax` promise chain and possibly is part of your issue

Comment: Maybe you are looking for an asynchronous function. Read this article https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Comment: Thanks guys.  I tried using Promise.resovle(...) and also removed the success/error callback from the ajax function, but not luck so far.

Comment: The reason I know that _doPostBack gets called early is that the my ".each" loop updates a bunch of selectpickers and writes those values to a database (using the ExecuteServiceMethod function calls - each call updates one of the items).  I see the selectpickers update correctly, then when the postback gets called, the data gets re-loaded from the database and re-displayed, and then I see that only some of the selectpickers show correct values.  This tells me that the postback happened before all the items updated in dB.  If I then re-load the page, all the items look correct.

Answer (score -1):

try wrapping like this: `Promise.resolve($.ajax(...))`

edit: you can also try removing the success and error callbacks in the ajax function

edit edit: also try catching any errors on your Promise.all

Comment: Using Promise.resolve() is an anti pattern for method that already returns a promise

Comment: Thanks.  See my comment above. Neither of these seemed to help and "try-catch" around Promise.all didn't catch any errors.  Really puzzled.